# Rails: TailwindCSS (via gem) is generating a CSS file that doesn't have some of the classes included in the Tailwind documentation

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I have a rails project using Tailwind for CSS.

My `tailwind.config.js` looks like this:

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ]
}
```

My Gemfile.lock has this for tailwind versions:

```
    tailwindcss-rails (2.0.32-aarch64-linux)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tailwindcss-rails (2.0.32-arm64-darwin)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    tailwindcss-rails (2.0.32-x86_64-linux)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
```

This gem version correlates to Tailwind CSS v3.3.5:  [gem CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md)

When I run bin/dev to run the following standard Procfile:

```
web: env RUBY_DEBUG_OPEN=true bin/rails server -p 3000
css: bin/rails tailwindcss:watch
```

I am able to see my rails application and some of the CSS classes that I expect, but some are missing, for instance the `.hidden` class is not being recognized.

Here's where I'm calling it in my html.erb, for reference

```
<div id="dropdown" class="w-52 py-1 bg-white rounded-sm shadow flex-col justify-start items-start inline-flex hidden">
  <ul class="py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200" aria-labelledby="profile-dropdown">
    <% menu_items.each do |menu_item| %>
      <%= menu_item %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I look at what's generated that I can see in my Chrome Dev Tools Sources tab (assets/tailwind-fingerprintsha2324342.css) I don't see the `.hidden` class selector at all. I tried to include the whole file, but it's 700+ lines.

There is a `[hidden]` (attribute) selector, but not a `.hidden` class selector, even though the documentation references the class selector[Tailwind Display hidden Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#hidden)

Is there something else that I should be doing to get a more full CSS file from tailwind? For more context, there's also some width classes missing, like `w-44` `w-48` which is also in the documentation:

[Tailwind Width Documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width)

Thanks for any guidance you can provide!

Summary:

I added the hidden class, and expected it to result in `display:none` and instead, the element still showed, and the class wasn't even showing up in chrome dev tools.